# WebPart Properties Missing in WebPage

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, ssom, farm-admin

I have the issue where I am unable to edit the web-part in sharepoint page,[Similar to this blog-post](http://siddiq-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2017/08/unable-to-edit-web-part-in-page.html).And I found the solution by following below steps .

**Solution:**

1. Open Internet Explorer, select the Tools button , and then select
   Compatibility View settings.
2. Under Add this website, enter the URL of the site you want to add to
   the list, and then select Add

But I would like to apply this to all my end users through developer end by opting powershell script or through any css,js files .
Can any one help me how can I do this.

Comment: E.g. via a group policy you could possibly achieve the mentioned change to IE's settings, but IMO that's not the correct way of approaching the problem. Instead you should troubleshoot your page/web part and consider re-creating it or its functionalities if it's simply bugged. As the blog you linked suggests this isn't (always) an issue for all users, there's likely an external cause (e.g. browser, installed updates, etc.) for the issue.

Comment: I agree with @moe but what's your IE version and the SharePoint version? what I think it's a browser issue in case you are not using Project Server 2010

Comment: IE 11 and SharePoint 2013 OnPrem

Comment: I had applied at group-policy Level in Computer Configuration Level .
But finding no luck to solve ..